# How to install Kannel [Sms gateway] In Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, server, kannel

How to install Kannel sms gateway , what is required to install it, and what is the process step by step. Is their any solution for Installing it in easy steps. Please give me some solution or some ideas and thing any link or something
I have tried everything to install, even tried to install it in windows thought cygwin But I am still blank I required it for sms gateway. Its necessary to install kannel I am using phpmyadmin latest version and want to implement it in PHP website Please give me some ideas Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676995/kannel-sms-gateway-how-to-install-kannel-in-ubantu

Answer (score 0):

In order to install `Kannel`, download the tar from [here](http://www.kannel.org/download.shtml), then extract it on to your appropriate folder. Then make sure you've got a C compiler in order to perform a `./configure` and a `make` in your installation folder.

These might be helpful:

[Installing the gateway](http://www.kannel.org/download/1.4.4/userguide-1.4.4/userguide.html#AEN189)

Steps:

[Installing Kannel](https://mahtabrasheed.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/how-to-installconfigure-kannelsms-gateway-for-sending-sms-from-your-computer/)